# Changing MFC dialog from STA to MTA?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, com, mfc

I'm working on an API that has some COM interfaces. The problem is that the API communicates through an interface that must be implemented by the project that loads that API. So if I were to use the API, I would load it into my project and create a class that would implement the methods that would be called by the API to notify me of certain things or to pass me results.

This obviously becomes a marshalling nightmare. Furthermore, since there are also some intermediate objects that pass the calls through the API from different plugins and managers to all the objects that implement the methods to be called for notification that have registered themselves to the API notifier this is getting out of hand in terms of complexity.

I was thinking, to shorten the work needed to be done by the person that loads the API, if the API were to follow a free threading model, is it possible for a class generated by MFC such as a dialog to implement the COM interface needed for notifications? Keep in mind that such an object needs to be turned into an IStream and turned back into an interface on the API end so that the API can call these methods.

As far as I know, MFC dialogs are by default STA. Is there a way I can enforce them to change or to start in MTA? Is it even legal from COM's point of view? I'm trying to avoid creating another object to handle the notifications in another thread since it would complicate things. This API needs to be used in more than one place, sometimes in a GUI, sometimes in a service, etc.

Comment: It is not quite clear why you think of MTA in first place. An app with STA window, loads API, implements notification interfaces, passes to API object - everything lives in STA - what is the problem with this simplest scenario?

Comment: The API has a number of threads running for some tasks such as disk access, parsing etc. These threads need to change things in maps that are controlled by some managers, in other words, access to those maps needs to be thread-safe and it's handled by the manager. The problem is that these maps need to be accessed by the application that loads the API, the API doesn't create copies of it to pass along, that means that the API should control when it's ok to access these maps etc.

Comment: I know this isn't a good way to do things, but since it handles a lot of data we can't pass copies of that information. We need to let the loader know what the layout of the data is and where it can find it. The STA raises some errors that I can't even begin to understand but as soon as I create a thread from an STA and initialize com for multi-threaded purposes, it works fine.

Comment: Let me clarify this a bit more. The notifier holds a list of IStream objects that get turned into interfaces so that the notify methods can be called for every object registered. Upon registering the GUI STA object to be notified, the notification passes through to the GUI without any problem for the first call. If the notification is called again the CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream() function gives a catastrophic failure error. The stream is cloned before hand so that when released, the original stream remains in the list.

Comment: You typically use `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` once to unmarshal and then you use the obtained interface pointer further on.

Comment: That is actually what happens. Only once though, the second time things go haywire. I don't suppose the notifier could hold a list of unmarshalled pointers, could it?

Comment: I don't see how holding streams rather than pointers is going to be helpful. If you consider marhsaling as expensive operation, you still do part of it by creating streams. Just complete it by getting pointers back on the other end and keep pointers with you. Streams are a vehicle to get pointers through apartments, they are not good/useful for anything else.

Comment: Thank you. Holding the unmarshalled pointers actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding that API itself is not limited to controlling thread and your intent is to get notifications on background threads through COM sink interface.

Three are several ways to address the problem staying COM friendly in the same time. The simplest is to change global apartment model for the application, so that "main" GUI thread is initialized as MTA. While this might work, you might quickly find out that this is incompatible with something else, such as ActiveX control registered with "Arartment" threading model.

Another option is to violate COM threading guidelines slightly, so that API would use sink interface directly from background threads without marshaling it. This is going to work fine with MFC application prepared to receive calls on side threads, and is actually very easy to do (just voluntary pass sink interface pointer between threads/apartments on API side). The problem might com up later when the API is used by .NET client which detects cross apartment interface pointer use.

To make it COM friendly and still with STA threading on UI thread, you can implement the following scenario. API can be STA component which accepts sink interface passed in directly (COM object implemented by MFC class in STA, or even simpler thing such as COM interface implemented directly on window class etc.). API marshals sink interface pointer into MTA for use on worker threads (`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` and friends). API uses unmarshaled pointer to deliver notifications from MTA threads. This would normally include threda switching to original thread that you don't want, so in order to avoid it, the MFC side notification class should implement free threaded marshaler. This will change things so that unmarshaled interface pointer receives calls directly on worker threads, and MFC application will be responsible for thread synchronization (critical sections etc). This is STA, COM friendly, API worker threads and efficient in the same time.

Comment: So I truly have no way of doing it by simply making the GUI object implement the COM interface and be safe at the same time. Thank you for your input. I'll rethink the loading methodology a bit, maybe with a callbacks object.